# Bad system call (core dumped) /usr/share/man/man1

Tags: software-center, apparmor

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04.1 release 4.15.0-38-generic.

I know this or a similar question was asked a few months ago and there seemed to be a fix or a workaround in progress.

```
dpkg --list man-db
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend  
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
iF  man-db         2.8.3-2ubunt amd64        on-line manual pager
```

Every time I run Software Updater or try to install a new package it takes forever, and the reason seems to be lots of core dumps.  Here is a small sample:

> >
>
> usr/bin/mandb: zcat: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/pbmtomda.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE -q: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/pamfile.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: zcat: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/pamfile.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE -q: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/pnmtorast.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: zcat: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/pnmtorast.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
>   /usr/bin/mandb: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE -q: Bad system call (core dumped)

I believe AppArmor was identified as a possible culprit by someone at Astrill but I am not using any package called Astrill VPN. I have Expressvpn, the Ubuntu network managers, pptp-linux and openvpn.

I have tried reinstalling man-db and apparmor but nothing changes.

I am now on Ubuntu 19.4 and still getting these mandb error messages. Every software install or update takes ages because it gets to about 89% then starts looping through these error messages. I had hoped that waiting for a new release might eventually solve this on its own, but it seems not. Any clues on what is going on and assistance to fix this would be appreciated.
(The above edit was made by me but I wasn't signed in!)

Comment: Do you get the same results just running `zcat`? I assume so, but we should be sure. Might simplify things if you can just see the single failure and reproduce with a single command. Example: `echo "This is a test" | gzip | zcat`

Comment: No. Why did you 'assume so'? The result just returned "This is a test", as expected.

Comment: Because the output you show specifically complains about `zcat` over and over. Given you report that various parts of `man-db` are not at fault, testing your assertions are just a good idea.

Comment: Wondered if there had been any progress on this at all?  I have man-db         2.8.5-2      amd64  and am running Ubuntu 19.04. Every time I run Software Updater it is still looping through /usr/bin/mandb: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE -q: Bad system call (core dumped) :usr/bin:mandb: zcat: Bad system call (core dumped)

Comment: I expect this VPN is at fault; several of them hook themselves into the system in strange things and break the mechanisms that man-db uses to reduce its exposure to security vulnerabilities.  I also expect that e.g. "man man" will fail to display a manual page, since it uses a similar sandboxing mechanism.  Assuming that last is true, could you run "sudo strace -f -o $HOME/man.trace -s 1024 man --debug man" and send the resulting man.trace file from your home directory to cjwatson@ubuntu.com?

Comment: Er, I got my previous comment a bit mixed up.  Drop the "sudo" bit.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the debugging information by email.

This turns out to be the fault of ESET File Security.  I've applied workarounds for this program in the past, but apparently I needed to do a bit more.

Briefly, this is an anti-malware tool that injects code into every process that involves sending a message to a separate program on your machine any time certain events happen.  Now, man-db has its own security measures that are intended to defend against malicious documents somehow managing to exploit bugs in the tools that process them, and those involve restricting the system calls that those tools can make to only those that they're supposed to need in order to do text processing.  Unfortunately, what ESET is doing is quite hard to distinguish from what malware might decide to do, so these two security measures fight with each other.

My reluctant compromise (although ultimately I'd like to figure out something better) has been to detect when ESET is installed and allow a few more system calls in that case, but this is a difficult exercise and it's easy to miss some.  I've [committed a change](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/commit/?id=1249bdac4aa6650fecd1fe469e390d8339d5dd5c) to add another one to that list in response to your trace.  This will need to be backported to stable Ubuntu releases before you see the benefit of it, and due to other commitments I won't have time to start that process until at least the middle of next week.  In the meantime, you have a couple of options to get past this problem:

- Uninstall ESET File Security (temporarily or otherwise).
- Set the environment variable `MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1`.  This is a bit difficult to do persistently via graphical tools such as Software Updater, but if you're willing to use `apt` from a terminal then you can just remember to run `sudo MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 apt full-upgrade` or `sudo MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 apt install some-package` or whatever.

I'll update this answer once packages including my change are available.  (Unfortunately I have no good way to confirm that this is fixed all the way, so it's possible this will be a whack-a-mole exercise where we have to go round again.)

Comment: As it happens, I was prompted by Software Updater to run an update this morning so before I did so I ran sudo MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 apt full-upgrade but now I'm back in core dump mode again. :(  I suppose the changes in the latest release are updates to existing packages rather than a full distro upgrade, which might be why your suggested temp fix isn't helping.

Comment: So, I sent the link to this question to ESET and they told me that my version of their software was out of date. I don't recall ever receiving any emails or other notifications of any upgrades from them, but maybe that's something I need to diary to check for in the future. They recommended that instead of simply running an upgrade I should uninstall and reinstall their software, which I have done, and rebooted my machine. I have since run Software Updater and it completed without going into a loop, but since I ran it this morning I don't know if that proves the problem is fixed.

Comment: The ESET software version I am now on is 4.0.93.0 and I was previously on 4.0.81.0. As previously stated, I don't think ESET prompts you when a new release is available, or if they do, it isn't very obvious. In fact, I'd say none of their stuff is very obvious, as to remove ESET from Ubuntu you need to run a command-line prompt which isn't sudo apt-get remove eset. You need cd /opt/eset/esets/bin then sudo ./esets_gil

Comment: I have just run Software Updater again and it completed without looping, so it would seem that reinstalling ESET may have fixed the problem. Do I need to manually re-set the environment variable SECCOMP, and if so, what is the correct command, please?

Comment: The environment variable is only effective for the apt command that you pass it to.  It doesn't persist.